# Issues PDF printing in my Printing Class

Tags: java, swt

I created a class to print a PDF file.

The class opens a application window with a start button.

When the start button is clicked it opens a ProgressMonitorDialog that runs my PrintFile Class that allows the users to select a local printer and sends the printjob to my print method.

Everything runs correctly but the printjob is never sent to the printer.

I know that is gets past the print call

```
try {
    System.out.println("before\n");         
    pjob.print();
    System.out.println("after\n"); 
}
```

But the print method is never executed?  So I am not sure what pjob.print(); is doing.

```
 public class AplotPdfPrintLocal extends ApplicationWindow {

   private String userSelectedFile;

   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //                         Constructor                                 //
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public AplotPdfPrintLocal(String pdfFilePath) {
      super(null);
      this.userSelectedFile = "c:/Teamcenter/Tc8.3/portal/temp/james.pdf";
   }

   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //                             run()                                   //
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public void run() {
      setBlockOnOpen(true); // Don't return from open() until window closes
      open();  // Opens the main window
      Display.getCurrent().dispose();  // Dispose the display
   }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                         configureShell()                            //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {
   super.configureShell(shell);
   shell.setText("Print PDF");
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                         createContents()                            //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
  Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
  composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

  //final Button indeterminate = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
  //indeterminate.setText("Indeterminate");

  // Create the ShowProgress button
  Button showProgress = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
  showProgress.setText("Select Printer");

  final Shell shell = parent.getShell();

  // Display the ProgressMonitorDialog
  showProgress.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
     public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
        try {
           new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell).run(true, true, new PrintFile(userSelectedFile, true));
        } 
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
           MessageDialog.openError(shell, "Error", e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
           MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Cancelled", e.getMessage());
        }
     }
   });
   parent.pack();
   return composite;
}

//===============================================================
//    PrintFile Class
// =============================================================== 
class PrintFile extends Thread implements Printable, IRunnableWithProgress  {

  private String filename;
  private Boolean setupPaper;
  private File file; 
  private PrinterJob pjob;
  private FileInputStream fis;
  private FileChannel fc;
  private ByteBuffer bb;
  private PDFFile pdfFile;
  private PDFPrintPage pages;
  private PageFormat pfDefault;
  private Label pagenumlabel;

  public PrintFile(String filename, boolean setupPaper) {
     this.filename = filename;
     this.setupPaper = setupPaper;
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                              run()                                  //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  @Override
  public void run(IProgressMonitor arg0) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
     try {
        System.out.println("File: " + filename + "\n");
        file = new File(filename);
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        fc = fis.getChannel();
        bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
        pdfFile = new PDFFile(bb); 
        pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);

        pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        pfDefault = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
        Paper defaultPaper = new Paper();
        defaultPaper.setImageableArea(0, 0, defaultPaper.getWidth(), defaultPaper.getHeight());
        pfDefault.setPaper(defaultPaper);
        if (setupPaper) {
           pfDefault = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().pageDialog(pfDefault);
        }
        pjob.setJobName(file.getName());
        //System.out.println("File Name : " + file.getName() + "\n");
        if (pjob.printDialog()) {
           pfDefault = pjob.validatePage(pfDefault);
           Book book = new Book();
           book.append(pages, pfDefault, pdfFile.getNumPages());
           pjob.setPageable(book);
           try {
              pjob.print();
           }
           catch (PrinterException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                             print()                                 //
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  @Override
  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int index) throws PrinterException {
     System.out.println("Got in the Print\n");       
     int pagenum = index + 1;
     if ((pagenum >= 1) && (pagenum <= pdfFile.getNumPages())) {
        if (pagenumlabel != null) {
           pagenumlabel.setText(String.valueOf(pagenum));
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(pagenum);
        double pwidth = format.getImageableWidth();
        double pheight = format.getImageableHeight();
        double aspect = page.getAspectRatio();
        double paperaspect = pwidth / pheight;
        if (paperaspect < 1.0) {
           switch (format.getOrientation()) {
              case PageFormat.REVERSE_LANDSCAPE:
              case PageFormat.LANDSCAPE:
                   format.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
                   break;
              case PageFormat.PORTRAIT:
                   format.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
                   break;
           }
           pwidth = format.getImageableWidth();
           pheight = format.getImageableHeight();
           paperaspect = pwidth / pheight;
        }
        Rectangle imgbounds;
        int width;
        int height;
        if (aspect > paperaspect) {
           height = (int) (pwidth / aspect);
           width = (int) pwidth;
        } 
        else {
           width = (int) (pheight * aspect);
           height = (int) pheight;
        }
        imgbounds = new Rectangle((int) format.getImageableX(),
               (int) format.getImageableY(),
               width, height);

        PDFRenderer pgs = new PDFRenderer(page, g2, imgbounds, null, null);
        try {
           page.waitForFinish();
           pgs.run();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
          return PAGE_EXISTS;
     } 
     else {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I feel like I am missing something simple, but have no clue what it is?
I am really stuck on this issue and really need help to figure this out.

Thanks to all that can help me

**EDIT**
If I comment out the following code

```
if (pjob.printDialog()) {
```

The print comes right out!

But when it is not commented out, the printer selection dialog opens, click the OK button,
printer dialog closes and nothing ever happens

***EDIT***

After some testing, I have discovered the problem has something with the pjob.printDialog().

I removed the if statment and set it up like this.

```
 boolean ok = pjob.printDialog();
    System.out.println("OK value " + ok + "\n");
    //if (ok) {
       pfDefault = pjob.validatePage(pfDefault);
       Book book = new Book();
       book.append(pages, pfDefault, pdfFile.getNumPages());
       System.out.println("Print Job After : " + pjob + "\n");
       pjob.setPageable(book);
       try {
          pjob.print();
       }
       catch (PrinterException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

printDialog opens, I click OK - A print job is sent to the printer, but nothing prints out.
                   I click cancel - The print job is printed out as wanted

Comment: Just a hunch, but are you also getting a java.awt.HeadlessException (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html)?

Comment: I just opened my print queue and watched.  When I hit the ok button the job does appear in the print queue for less than a second.  So it is sending something.  Can it be that when printDialog returns true, it is sending a empty print job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% for sure why, but if I use the cross platform printDialog instead of a native printDialog - The code works as expected.

This is the working code

```
           PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
           PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
           PageFormat pfDefault = pjob.pageDialog(aset);
           pjob.setJobName(file.getName());
           pages.show(pjob);
           if (pjob.printDialog(aset)) {
              pfDefault = pjob.validatePage(pfDefault);
              Book book = new Book();
              book.append(pages, pfDefault, pdfFile.getNumPages());
              pjob.setPageable(book);
              try {

                 pjob.print(aset);

              }
              catch (PrinterException exc) {
                 System.out.println(exc);
              }
```